# Changing a histogram (creating a hole)

Tags: opencv, histogram

This is a histogram of a grayscaled image I have:

[INPUT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZyTEI.jpg)

I need it to be more like this:

[OUTPUT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/me55E.jpg)

And I wonder what's the best and efficient way to reach it. In general, I need n% (I guess n is between 0-20) of the image's area with the highest luminance to be brighter. Or (100-n)% to be darker. I tried chanigng each pixel's luminance one-by-one but it is highly ineffective.

Answer (score 0):

You should only change the pixels you find in the interest bin that you want to modify by assigning a smaller value